# Can we have an Ask Ubuntu blog like SuperUser?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a community blog?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1135/can-we-have-a-community-blog)

I noticed over on the [Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/) that they are [looking for writers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2278/the-super-user-blog-is-looking-for-writers) for the [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/).

Can we please have an Ask Ubuntu blog? Not only that, but can we also have someone oversee suggestions for articles for the blog?

Ideas:

- Tutorials on using Ubuntu applications / configuring hardware
- Reviews / comparisons of software
- News related to Ubuntu releases or whatever

Comment: Guess [this has already been discussed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1135/can-we-have-a-community-blog) :)